# NullPointerException when trying to use text to speech to speak text message out loud

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sms, text-to-speech

I'm getting an `Exception` when trying to get text to speech to speak sms text upon arrival and it's giving me a `NullPointerException` and I can seem to figure out was it's wanting me to do or where exactly the error lies. What could possibly be my problem?

**Error Log**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.fegeley.handsfreetexting.TTS: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2677)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:170)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.fegeley.handsfreetexting.TTS.speakText(TTS.java:52)
        at com.fegeley.handsfreetexting.TTS.onReceive(TTS.java:74)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2669)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:170)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.fegeley.handsfreetexting;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TTS tts;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tts = new TTS();
    tts.giveContext(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    tts.onPause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**TTS.java**

```
package com.fegeley.handsfreetexting;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Kayne on 1/14/2015.
 */
public class TTS extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static Context context;
TextToSpeech tts;

public TTS(){
}

public static void giveContext(Context con){
    context = con;
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    tts = new TextToSpeech(context,
            new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {
                    if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                        tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                    }
                }
            });
}

public void onPause(){
    if(tts !=null){
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
}

public void speakText(String toSpeak){
    HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hash.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM,
            String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION));
    tts.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, hash);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";
    //if (bundle != null)
    //{
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";
        //}
        //---display the new SMS message---
        speakText(str);
    }
}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.fegeley.handsfreetexting" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.fegeley.handsfreetexting.TTS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "tts" object on Line 52 in NULL.

You seems to be initializing it in "onCreate()" of BroadcastReceiver.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    tts = new TextToSpeech(context,
            new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener()
```

Note that BroadcastReceiver class **do not have any onCreate() Activity-styled call back method.**

I guess you assumed that system will invoke onCreate() of BroadcastReceiver class. That is not true for BroadcastReceiver.

You can initialize "tts" object in onReceive() as below:

```
public void onReceive(Context context1, Intent intent) {
    //---get the SMS message passed in---

    tts = new TextToSpeech(context,
            new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {
                    if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                        tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Also, change following line in your **MainActivity.java**

Remove : `tts.giveContext(this);`  Add:`TTS.giveContext(getApplicationContext());`

This change is to prevent **ReceiverCallNotAllowedException**

Comment: After applying what you suggested, I tested the code and when I receive an sms while the app is still open, it gives me an error saying 'speak failed: not bound to TTS engine'
But when I receive an sms while the app is closed, it still says 'NullPointerException at TTS.java:45'

Comment: which is 
`public void onReceive(Context context1, Intent intent) {
        (line 45)tts = new TextToSpeech(context,
                new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInit(int status) {
                        if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                            tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                        }
                    }
                });`

Comment: 1.When app is closed,and SMS is received, the TTS.giveContext(getApplicationContext()) can't give you context (as app may be killed). You can save App context using below code: public class MyApp extends Application
{
    private static Context _appContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        _appContext = this;
    }

    public static Context getAppContext()
    {
        return _appContext;
    }
}

Comment: and fetch code in onReceive() like this: context=MyApp.getAppContext();For Error: 'speak failed: not bound to TTS engine'  you need to check if TTS Engine is initialized properly. **The solution I gave will prevent the NullPointerException.** , which was the original question. You may search for "'speak failed: not bound to TTS engine'" error seperately too, as it is not part of your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate a TextToSpeech object in a broadcast receiver. Your code

```
speakText(str);
```

at the end of `onReceive` is called before the Text To Speech call `onInit` thus you get speak failed not bound to TTS engine.
When an SMS arrives the system instantiate a TTS object as defined in your manifest. It has nothing to do with the tts you instantiates in your MainActivity.
You did not get `NPE` when your app is opened because the `static` declaration of `context` in your `TTS` class and you instantiate an object in your `MainActivity`, thus `context` is not null and therefore the `tts` object you declare in `onCreate` or in `onReceive` as **AADTechnical** suggested is not null.
When your app is close the `tts` object declared in `MainActivity` is destroyed thus the `context` member in any `TTS` object initiates without having one calls `giveContext` woud be null. And `giveContext` would not be called by the system when it instantiates a `TTS` object thus `context` is null and the `tts` object instantiates in the class is null and you get `NPE`.

What you need to do is to create a `service` class where a TTS object is instantiated and start your service in `onReceive`

```
public class SMSService extends Service
{
    // instantiate a TTS object in this class
}
```

and

```
public class TTS extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // get your SMS message
        // and then start the SMSService passing the message in the intent bundle
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the library but the stack trace tells that the NullPointerException occured in TTS.java on line 52:

```
str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
```

That means msgs[i] is null although it was assigned one line before that:

```
msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
```

Thus createFromPdu returned null.
Since createFromPdu seems to be a framework method it is very likely that pdus[i] which you retrieved from the bundle is null.
Please make sure that you have written "pdus" into the bundle before you read them.

regards,
Max

Comment: Actually, I just realized this, there was 16 extra lines in TTS.java where the imports were and I missed them when copying to the question, so line 52 was actually 16 lines up. I will edit the question to fix that.

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen the inconsistency in the querstion, sorry. AADTechnical's solution might be it.